# Does this qualify as a MatPlotLib Bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is an extreme situation, but I ran into it easily. My function does interesting things near zero, but also diverges frequently. I can clip it to solve this problem, but is this also a bug, and if so how should it be reported?

It appears that when the vertical data has a large range, and the vertical scale is small, matplotlib takes longer and longer to decide how to draw a dashed line between extreme points. Solid lines 'b-' instead of 'b--' are not affected as far as I can see.

Paste the different values of 'scale' to vary the slowness

using python 2.7 and mpl 1.3.1 on OSX

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1.0E+07, -1.0E+07, 1.0E+06]
x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

# narrower range takes longer to draw dashed lines  .e.g 'b--'
scale_fast =           [0.0, 2.0, -100.0, 100.0]
scale_two_seconds =    [0.0, 2.0,  -10.0,  10.0]
scale_twenty_seconds = [0.0, 2.0,  -1.0,    1.0]
scale_very_long =      [0.0, 2.0,  -0.1,    0.1]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'b--')     # dashed line is slow, solid line OK
plt.axis(scale_two_seconds)
print "um..."
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you specify the time difference you are getting between your scales? I seem to find not a big difference when I run your code using the different scales

Comment: What backend are you using?  If it is the osx backend see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1758.  Work around is to use one of the agg based backends (ex qtagg).

Comment: Bingo! Yep I am using OSX and the issue in the link you provided seems to be exactly what I've seen. Thank you @tcaswell. I will check the github issues from now on.